# How to testfor if an ArmorStand got killed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a one-command creation that adds sports to Minecraft. I want to be able to testfor when you kill an ArmorStand. I tried to use the `scoreboard` command but it cannot be used for testing ArmorStand kills.
So, *how do I testfor when a player kills an ArmorStand?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try summoning an invisible ArmorStand named "Rudolf" at every visible ArmorStand, then tesing if it has another on next to it:

Plug this into a RS clock (or use the 1.9 Command blocks):

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ /testfor @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Rudolf,c=2]
```

If the testfor doesn't find anything, execute this command:

```
 /execute @e[type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1,CustomName:"Rudolf"}
```

Then, connect this command into a RS clock (or use the 1.9 Command blocks):

```
/execute @e[name=Rudolf] ~ ~ ~ /testfor @e[type=ArmorStand,name=!Rudolf,c=2]
```

If the testfor doesn't find anything, execute these commands:

```
/YOURCOMMAND(S)

/kill @e[name=Rudolf]
```